Can't connect to an Ethereum node using WEB3_PROVIDER_URI environment variable in web3.py
I am trying to connect to an Ethereum node using the environment variable WEB3_PROVIDER_URI in web3.py. The documentation says:

Alternatively, you can set the environment variable WEB3_PROVIDER_URI before starting your script, and web3 will look for that provider first.

I set the environment variable and imported the w3 object:
from web3.auto.gethdev import w3

However, upon checking whether the connection succedded:
w3.is_connected()

I am getting False.

Make sure that the WEB3_PROVIDER_URI environment variable is correctly set to the URL of your Ethereum node. You can verify this in your terminal before running the script using the command: echo $WEB3_PROVIDER_URI.

The variable is properly set and I can output it using echo $WEB3_PROVIDER_URI. I also checked the availability of the variable inside Python by importing the os module and running os.getenv("WEB3_PROVIDER_URI").

Okay. And are you running the node locally? Or, are you using some third party RPC provider?

I'm using Alchemy. When I tested the connection using HTTPProvider, everything works fine.

Can you please share the url of the doc that you’re following?

https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#provider-via-environment-variable

Sorry for responding late. I've tried that, but it's returning False on my end too. I think you can raise an issue on their GitHub, and share the url, so that I can engage with the corresponding thread too.

I finally made it work. I used from web3.auto import w3 and it worked.

Oh okay, you mean without .gethdev?

Yes, without .gethdev.

That’s great to know.

Instead of:
from web3.auto.gethdev import w3

I used
from web3.auto import w3

Which returned true on the status of the connection:
w3.is_connected()

The environment variable WEB3_PROVIDER_URI has to be initialized.
